# How to include only one class

Tags: dependencies, ivy

I am attempting to use the log4j-1.2.17 jar, and I only want the EnhancedPatternLayout class.

My ivy dependency looks like:

```
<dependency org="log4j" name="log4j" rev="1.2.17">
        <include name="org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout"/>
        </dependency>
```

The ivy resolver isn't complaining about what I've wrote, but I don't seem to be able to grab it. Appending `.class` doesn't seem to do the trick either, so I figure I'm going about it the wrong way. How can I make it so I only get that class specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, not possible to download just a single class. When you declare a dependency it's normally against a specific point in time of a java package whose classes are captured collectively in a jar file.

The jar/was/ear formats were invented to make compiled java artifacts portable. It is jars that are stored and versioned in the [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/) repository.